# fgets reads more than maximum characters

Tags: c, file-io, fgets

I am just curious how fgets() reads input in C.
As per syntax the second arguement is maximum characters to be read(n-1). So this is a piece of code where I am trying to copy contents of one file to another:

```
void myCopy(char* src, char* dest)
{
        FILE *fp_src;
        FILE *fp_dest;
        fp_src=fopen(src, "r");
        fp_dest=fopen(dest,"w");
        char buff[2];
        while(fgets(buff,2,fp_src))
        {
                fputs(buff,fp_dest);
        }
        return;
}
```

Here max characters to be read = 2-1=**1**, How does this copies every line of source to destination perfectly? Shouldn't it skip to next line after reading first character itself?

Comment: "*Shouldn't it skip to next line*'. Why would it? `fgets` will just read one character at a time from the file (because one char is needed for the NUL terminator each time). Each `fgets` will continue from where the last `fgets` stopped. Nothing is skipped. How/where do you think the skipping occurs?

Comment: Since `fgets()` reads as many characters as it can fit into the buffer, up to and including a newline (leaving any characters that don't fit to be read by the next input function), your code is making `fgets()` act like an inefficient `getc()` (though it does leave you with a string, not a character, but even that can be fixed with `getc()` by using byte zero of a 2-byte array).  You're allowed to do that, even though it isn't sensible. You'd have a bigger problem if you specified the size `1` instead of `2`.

Comment: "Shouldn't it skip to next line after reading first character itself?" --> No.